# Primes of the form $2^p-p$ or $2^p+p$ with $p$ prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I have to find some prime numbers of the form $2^p-p$ or $2^p+p$ with $p$ a prime number. The question is how many of these prime numbers there are?

I have no clue of how this can be done. Thanks and please excuse my English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let  $p_1 = 2^p + p$ and $p_2 = 2^p - p$. Trivially, $p = 3$ is a solution. Let $p > 3$. Then either $p$ is of the form $6k+1$ or it is of the form $6k+5$.

**Case 1**: $p$ is of the form $6k+1$. In this case, $p_1 \equiv 2^{6k+1} + 6k + 1 \equiv 64^k*2 + 1 \equiv 4^k*2 + 1 \equiv 4*2 + 1 \equiv 3(\mod 6)$ hence $p_1$ cannot be a prime.

**Case 2**: $p$ is of the form $6k+5$. In this case, $p_2 \equiv 2^{6k+5} - 6k - 5 \equiv 3 (\mod 6)$ hence $p_2$ cannot be a prime.

Thus the only solution is when $p = 3$.

Comment: $2^5+5=37$ and $2^13-13=8179$ bot are prime and of the form $6k+1$

Comment: @O.Arcila - Yes but $2^5 - 5 =27$ is not a prime. I think your question requires more clarity. Does your question required both $2^p + p$ and $2^p - p$ to be primes for a given $p$?

Comment: not excuse me my English is not very good i mean that i find numbers of the bot forms separatly. thanks.

Comment: Hi, can you elaborate more on the case 1 please.

Comment: @O.Arcila In that case, $\{2,3,5,13,19\}$ yield solutions. Other _possible_ solutions with $p<1000$ include $\{ 89, 317, 701\}$. They may not be solutions because I used a deterministic version of Miller-Rabin (with all primes $<=41$ as witnesses), and those numbers fall outside of the range where those witness guarantee primality.